# Create new layer on top off parent layer

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a `CCScrollView` that I need to add a custom notification too. I need the notification to be centered however because the `CCScrollView` is larger than the height of the device it centers it based on the height of the `CCScrollview`( which in most cases positions it too low).

To counteract this I suspect I need to create a new layer on top of this. How do I do this?

My code to add the custom notification

```
-(void)loadNotification {

    //Import Level Up Scene
    CCNode *notification = [CCBReader load:@"notification-stamina"];
    CGPoint centerPos = ccp([CCDirector sharedDirector].viewSize.width * 0.5, [CCDirector sharedDirector].viewSize.height * 0.5);
    notification.position = centerPos;
    [self addChild:notification];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the notification as sibling of the scroll view (both having the same parent) rather than as child of the scroll view. That way the notification position is independent of the scroll view.